# What is a faster solution for integer coordinates in circle of radius x

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to create a method that returns the count of integer coordinates within a circle of radius rad but I believe my current solution is too slow. What would you recommend for a better implementation? I'd like to code the solution myself as I'm still a beginner.

This is my current solution:

```
def points(rad):
    possiblePoints = []
    negX = -rad
    negY = -rad
     #creating a list of all possible points from -rad,-rad to rad, rad
    while(negX <= rad):
        while(negY <= rad):
            possiblePoints.append((negX,negY))
            negY += 1
        negY = -rad
        negX += 1

    count = 0
    index=0
    negX = -rad
    negY = -rad
    distance = 0
     #counting the possible points for distances within rad
    for i in possiblePoints:
        for j in range(0,2):
            distance += (possiblePoints[index][j])**2
        distance = distance**(0.5)
        if(distance<=rad):
            count+=1
        distance = 0
        index += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Please fix indentation so your code is runnable.
Also: do you mean from the origin?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the indentation

Comment: What happened is you get negative `rad`?

Comment: @DavidWinder That's a QA question, and should be asserted. But I think it's not the point of the question being asked.

Comment: I didn't consider negative rad since I'm only using this myself but I suppose I could  edit it for that consideration

Comment: I give some other idea for a better algorithm in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things can definitely be made faster than using lots of unnecessary loops.
Why not "build" and "check" in the same loop?
Also, you can make this (almost) a one-liner with the help of `product` from itertools:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

def points(rad):
    x = np.arange(-rad, rad + 1)
    return len([(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in product(x, x) if p1 ** 2 + p2 ** 2 <= rad ** 2])

# Examples    
print(points(5))
>> 81
print(points(1))
>> 5
print(points(2))
>> 13
```

The list comprehension gives the actual points, if that's of any use.
Good luck!

---

Some explanations in case needed:
`x` is just a list of integers between (and including) `-rad` and `rad`.
`product(x, x)` is the Cartesian product of x and itself, thus all the points in the square defined by both coordinates being between `-rad` and `rad`.
The list comprehension returns only points with a distance from the origin smaller or equal to `rad`.
The function returns the length of this list.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'd have to look into some of the tools you've used as I've never seen them before. Still, I didn't get the same return as my solution so I may have not been clear. rad = 1 should return 5, rad = 2 should return 13 rad = 3 should return 29 etc.

Comment: Sorry, had a small mistake. Fixed now. I'll add some explanations too.

Answer (score 2):

A point *(x, y)* is within the radius given *x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>≤r<sup>2</sup>*. We can calculate the number of coordinates for a *fixed* *y*-value as:

*n<sub>y</sub>=1 + 2×⌊√(r<sup>2</sup>-y<sup>2</sup>)⌋*

If we then slice *y* between *0* and *r*, and we count each *n<sub>y</sub>* for *y>0* twice, we obtain the total number, so we can calculate this as:

```
import numpy as np
from math import floor

def total(radius):
    r0 = floor(radius)
    ys = np.arange(1, r0+1)
    halves = 2 * np.sum(2*np.floor(np.sqrt(radius * radius - ys * ys)) + 1)
    return halves + 1 + 2 * r0
```

We thus calculate for each "layer" the number of integral coordinates, and we double each layer, since there is a "co-layer" with the same number of integral coordinates in the opposite direction. We then add the number of coordinates with *y=0* which is *1+2×⌊r⌋*.

The above thus works in *O(r)* with *r* the radius of the circle.

Sample output:

```
>>> total(0)
1.0
>>> total(0.1)
1.0
>>> total(1)
5.0
>>> total(1.1)
5.0
>>> total(1.42)
9.0
>>> total(2)
13.0
>>> total(3)
29.0
```

A slower alternative in *O(r<sup>2</sup>)* is to generate a grid, and then perform a comparison in bulk on it, like:

```
import numpy as np
from math import floor

def total_slow(radius):
    r0 = floor(radius)
    xs = np.arange(-r0, r0+1)
    ys = xs[:, None]
    return np.sum(xs*xs+ys*ys <= radius*radius)
```

The above is however useful if we want to verify that our solution works. For example:

```
>>> total_slow(0)
1
>>> total_slow(1)
5
>>> total_slow(2)
13
>>> total_slow(3)
29
```

produces the same results, but we can use this to verify that it always produces the same result for a large number of radiuses, for example:

```
>>> [total(r) == total_slow(r) for r in np.arange(0, 10, 0.03)]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

This thus means that we verified that the two generated the same result for `0`, `0.03`, `0.06`, etc. up to `10`. The above is of course not a formal proof of the correctness, but it gives us *some* empricial evidence.

### Performance

We can test performance by using the `timeit` module, and we tested the algorithms with three radiusses, each experiment was repeated 10'000 times:

```
>>> timeit(partial(total, 1.23), number=10000)
0.11901686200144468
>>> timeit(partial(total, 12.3), number=10000)
0.1255619800031127
>>> timeit(partial(total, 123), number=10000)
0.1318465179974737

>>> timeit(partial(total_slow, 1.23), number=10000)
0.11859546599953319
>>> timeit(partial(total_slow, 12.3), number=10000)
0.15540562200112618
>>> timeit(partial(total_slow, 123), number=10000)
1.3335393390007084

>>> timeit(partial(total_slow, 1.23), number=10000)
0.11859546599953319
>>> timeit(partial(total_slow, 12.3), number=10000)
0.15540562200112618
>>> timeit(partial(total_slow, 123), number=10000)
1.3335393390007084

>>> timeit(partial(points, 1), number=10000)
0.1152820099996461
>>> timeit(partial(points, 12), number=10000)
3.7115225509987795
>>> timeit(partial(points, 123), number=10000)
433.3227958699972
```

With `points` the method of [@ShlomiF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53575405/67579), we here use integral numbers, since for a radius with a floating point number, this method will produce incorrect results.

We thus obtain the following table:

```
radius   total    total_slow    points
1.23     0.119         0.119     0.115*
12.3     0.125         0.155     3.711*
123.     0.131         1.334   433.323*

* with integral radiuses
```

This is expected behavior if we take time complexity into account: eventually a linear approach will outperform a quadratic approach.

Comment: Thank you for you help, WIllem. It will take me some time to understand everything fully but I do appreciate your effort in answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

- For faster, the same logic but a quick numpy solution :

  def count_in(radius):
      r=radius+1
      X,Y=np.mgrid[-r:r,-r:r]
      return (X**2 + Y**2 <= radius**2).sum()

You will speed your algorithm by ~x30 generally. Detail explanations later.

- For algorithm, I suggest you a better way :
  [image]

Just follow the blue line, evaluating pink area. Have fun.

Explanations  for radius=3 :

```
In [203]: X
Out[203]: 
array([[-4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4],
       [-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3],
       [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2],
       [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3]])

In [204]: Y
Out[204]: 
array([[-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3]])

In [205]: X*X+Y*Y
Out[205]: 
array([[32, 25, 20, 17, 16, 17, 20, 25],
       [25, 18, 13, 10,  9, 10, 13, 18],
       [20, 13,  8,  5,  4,  5,  8, 13],
       [17, 10,  5,  2,  1,  2,  5, 10],
       [16,  9,  4,  1,  0,  1,  4,  9],
       [17, 10,  5,  2,  1,  2,  5, 10],
       [20, 13,  8,  5,  4,  5,  8, 13],
       [25, 18, 13, 10,  9, 10, 13, 18]])
```

And finally :

```
In [207]: (X**2 + Y**2 <= 3**2)
Out[207]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [208]: (X**2 + Y**2 <= 3**2).sum() # True is one
Out[208]: 29
```