# Algorithm for integer solutions of a circle?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I am trying to search for integer solutions to the equation:

```
y^2 + x^2 = 2n^2
```

If I search this in wolfram alpha, they are all found almost immediately even for very large n. When I implemented a brute force approach it was very slow:

```
def psearch(n, count):
    for x in range(0, n):
        for y in range(0, n):
            if x*x + y*y == 2*n**2:
                print(x,y)
                count += 1
    return count
```

So I assume there is a much faster way to get all of the integer solutions to the equation above. How can I do this in python so that it will have much lower runtime?

Note: I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575306/what-is-a-faster-solution-for-integer-coordinates-in-circle-of-radius-x) however it is about finding lattice points *within* a circle not the integer solutions to the equation of the circle. Also I am interested in finding the specific solutions **not just the number of solutions**.

Edit: I am still looking for something an order of magnitude faster. Here is an example: n=5 should have 12 integer solutions to find what those should be search this equation on [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%20%3D%202%285%29%5E2).

Edit 2: @victor zen gave a phenomenal answer to the problem. Can anyone think of a way to optimize his solution further?

Comment: That's a really inefficient search through a search space guaranteed to contain no solutions - `x*x+y*y` will always be less than `2*n**2`, for the values of `x` and `y` you're looking at.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand unless I made a typo. x^2+y^2=2(5)^2 has 12 integer solutions...

Comment: n is a fixed integer x and y are the variables. Should I clarify this in the question?

Comment: With this algorithm, how do you intend to find the solution x=1, y=1 for x^2 + y^2 = 2*(1)^2

Comment: @Cid: The question requires all solutions, not just one solution.

Comment: @PatrickMaynard: There may be 12 solutions for n=5, but your code won't try any of them.

Comment: @user2357112 oh yes, I just noticed the s at *solutionS*. I guess it's time to get a cofee

Comment: I agree I'm not sure it works I had some more stuff in there I omitted to make it less cluttered and might bee wrong as is

Comment: haha @Cid I was wondering if I missed something there

Comment: Very interested to know about the 12 integer solutions for  x^2 + y^2 = 2*(1)^2

Comment: This is a [homogeneous Diophantine equation of degree 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Homogeneous_equations), and the wiki article I just linked talks about how to solve them. It might require more math expertise than you can bring to bear, though.

Comment: This question *may* fit [the math site of the network](https://math.stackexchange.com/) more than SO

Comment: @user2357112 thanks and yes I think your right that is a little much I was hoping there wouldn't be a very hard way to implement this in python

Comment: @Cid I thought it wasn't that hard of an algorithm but apparently it must be. I posted here because I assumed it was simple and someone would know. Do you think enough people on math exchange know python?

Comment: @Cid I think they might consider it off topic...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your algorithm, you're searching for all possible y values. This is unnecessary. The trick here is to realize that

```
y^2 + x^2 = 2n^2
```

directly implies that

```
y^2 = 2n^2-x^2
```

so that means you only have to check that 2n^2-x^2 is a perfect square. You can do that by

```
y2 = 2*n*n - x*x 
#check for perfect square
y = math.sqrt(y2)
if int(y + 0.5) ** 2 == y2:
    #We have a perfect square.
```

Also, in your algorithm, you are only checking x values up to n. This is incorrect. Since y^2 will always be positive or zero, we can determine the highest x value we need to check by setting y^2 to its lowest value (i.e 0). Consequentially, we need to check all integer x values satisfying

```
x^2 <= 2n^2
```

which reduces to

```
abs(x) <= sqrt(2)*n.
```

Combine this with the optimization of only checking the top quadrant, and you have an optimized psearch of

```
def psearch(n):
    count = 0
    top = math.ceil(math.sqrt(2*n*n))
    for x in range(1, top):
        y2 = 2*n*n - x*x 
        #check for perfect square
        y = math.sqrt(y2)
        if int(y + 0.5) ** 2 == y2:
            count+=4
    return count
```

Comment: Wow what an answer! This is extremely helpful! Can you think of any way to optimize it further?

Comment: That's certainly the low-hanging fruit optimization, but it still runs in pseudopolynomial time, O(n) where n is the value of the input instead of the size of the input. It works up to much bigger values than (a bug-fixed version of) the code in the question, but it's still quite limited. A better algorithm can go way further - it's obvious from the runtime that Wolfram Alpha isn't doing anything so simple, for example.

Comment: (Also that `math.sqrt` is going to cause problems if you go high enough.)

Comment: I agree that there is probably much faster ways to do this. Just how complicated do you think wolfram alpha's algorithm is? Is there an algorithm faster that you can think of that is relatively concise?

Comment: This problem is equivalent to the problem of counting Pythagorean triples with a given hypotenuse. Somewhere deep in a math journal, there might be a more efficient solution, but there isn't one that's widely known and will probably involve some heavy number theory.

In regards to Wolfram Alpha, the query "number of integer solutions to x^2+y^2 = 2000000000" is translated to the Mathamatica code 

    Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 2000000000, {x, y}, Integers]

which merely attempts to find a few solutions.

Comment: @victorzeng: Unless you're thinking of a different approach than I am, the coefficient of 2 on n^2 means this is not equivalent to counting Pythagorean triples.

Comment: @victorzeng: Also, Wolfram Alpha reports an exact value under "Number of integer solutions", so it's definitely not just looking for a few solutions.

Comment: A quick documentation search turns up [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html#13440227) showing that Mathematica knows how to solve arbitrary quadratic Diophantine equations in two variables (which this equation is, for fixed `n`), as well as exactly how Mathematica does it.

Comment: And here is the reference used by Mathematica: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1990-55-191/S0025-5718-1990-1023762-3/S0025-5718-1990-1023762-3.pdf

Comment: @OneLyner thanks I am going to try to implement this later!

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to search inside the first octant `y>0`, `x<y` (the four solutions `(±n, ±n)` are obvious and by symmetry a solution `(x, y)` yields 8 copies `(±x, ±y)`, `(±y, ±x)`).

By monotonicity, for a given `y` there is at most one `x`. You can find it by following the circular arc incrementally, decreasing `y` then adjusting `x`. If you maintain the condition `x²+y²≤2n²` as tightly as possible, you get the code below which is optimized to use only elementary integer arithmetic (for efficiency, `2x` is used instead of `x`).

```
    x, y, d= 2 * n, 2 * n, 0
    while y > 0:
        y, d= y - 2, d - y + 1
        if d < 0:
            x, d= x + 2, d + x + 1
        if d == 0:
            print(x >> 1, '² + ', y >> 1, '² = 2.', n, '²', sep='')
```

Here are all solutions for `n` between `1` and `100`:

```
7² + 1² = 2.5²
14² + 2² = 2.10²
17² + 7² = 2.13²
21² + 3² = 2.15²
23² + 7² = 2.17²
28² + 4² = 2.20²
31² + 17² = 2.25²
35² + 5² = 2.25²
34² + 14² = 2.26²
41² + 1² = 2.29²
42² + 6² = 2.30²
46² + 14² = 2.34²
49² + 7² = 2.35²
47² + 23² = 2.37²
51² + 21² = 2.39²
56² + 8² = 2.40²
49² + 31² = 2.41²
63² + 9² = 2.45²
62² + 34² = 2.50²
70² + 10² = 2.50²
69² + 21² = 2.51²
68² + 28² = 2.52²
73² + 17² = 2.53²
77² + 11² = 2.55²
82² + 2² = 2.58²
84² + 12² = 2.60²
71² + 49² = 2.61²
79² + 47² = 2.65²
85² + 35² = 2.65²
89² + 23² = 2.65²
91² + 13² = 2.65²
92² + 28² = 2.68²
98² + 14² = 2.70²
103² + 7² = 2.73²
94² + 46² = 2.74²
93² + 51² = 2.75²
105² + 15² = 2.75²
102² + 42² = 2.78²
112² + 16² = 2.80²
98² + 62² = 2.82²
97² + 71² = 2.85²
113² + 41² = 2.85²
115² + 35² = 2.85²
119² + 17² = 2.85²
123² + 3² = 2.87²
119² + 41² = 2.89²
126² + 18² = 2.90²
119² + 49² = 2.91²
133² + 19² = 2.95²
137² + 7² = 2.97²
124² + 68² = 2.100²
140² + 20² = 2.100²
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize this algorithm maybe by considering only one quadrant only and the multiplying  by 4.

```
import math
def psearch(n, count):
  for x in range( 0 , 2*n  + 1):
    ysquare = 2*(n**2) - x * x
    if (ysquare <0):
      break
    y = int(math.sqrt(ysquare))

    if ysquare ==  y * y :
      print(x,y)
      count+=1

  return count


print(psearch(13241324,0) * 4)
```

OUTPUT

```
(1269716, 18682964)
(1643084, 18653836)
(11027596, 15134644)
(12973876, 13503476)
(13241324, 13241324)
(13503476, 12973876)
(15134644, 11027596)
(18653836, 1643084)
(18682964, 1269716)
36
```

Comment: Thank you! I like this but I'm still looking for something a lot quicker than the original. It does not like it when I make n very large.

Comment: @PatrickMaynard I have optimized the algorithm to run on `O(n)` time complexity