# Finding coordinates lies inside a circle for given conditions

Tags: java, python

I'm wondering for days on a task given by my university. Here is the problem.

I have an boolean expression. Say `x*2 + y*8 == given_value`. I need to find the all the integer coordinates lies inside a circle with a given radius, such that whose coordinates returns true for the boolean expression.

The problem is how can I generate the all the coordinates inside a circle.

Even if the radius has some big value such as 10^4.

Any answer based on Java or Python is appreciated

Comment: Hint: for 0<=theta<=pi/4 the integers (m,n) satisfy n<=m<=r for radius r

Comment: Another hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575306/what-is-a-faster-solution-for-integer-coordinates-in-circle-of-radius-x

Comment: @mrblewog thank you very much they helped me!

Comment: Then would you mind clicking the little triangles next to the comment to show they’ve been useful?